# ravendb check if item is in list

Tags: ravendb

How can I query RavenDB for all "Products" which are in a list of categories?

Lets say I want all products that their category is "1" or "2" or "3". The list of categories(1,2,3) should by dynamic. it will change based on user input.

Comment: Can the Product be in multiple categories?

Comment: No. It cant... A product can have only 1 category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a product can only have one category then it would something like this:

```
products = from p in session.Query<Product>()
        where p.Category.In(new[] { 1,2,3 })
        select p;
```

If multiple categories for a product the following should work:

```
products = from p in session.Query<Product>()
        where p.Categories.Any(new[] { 1,2,3 })
        select p;
```

Comment: where p.Category.In(new[] { 1,2,3 }). The "In" is not compiling

Comment: Did you add "using Raven.Client.Linq;"?